# javascript toggle does not insert class name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a homepage to study javascript.

I have a problem making drop down menu.
I used `classList.toggle("show")` to make `#dropDownContent` element's class have `show`. I used chrome developer tool and check #dropDownContent's class changes. but it doesn't change.

Here's my code. Where should I change?

```js
function mypageMenuDropDown() {
  var dropdownContent = document.getElementById('dropDownContent');
  dropdownContent.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul id="header">
      <li id="logo"><a class="headerDiv" href='.'>FLAGTAG</a></li>
      <div id="menu">
        <li id="login"><a class="headerDiv" href="model/logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li>
        <li id="mypage"><button class="headerDiv" onclick="mypageMenuDropDown()">MYPAGE</a></li>
          <div id="dropDownContent" class="dropDownContent">
            <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=join">CALANDER</a>
            <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=routine">ROUTINE</a>
            <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=DIET">DIET</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: do you have css for class `show` ?

Comment: Are you sure that your element id `dropDownContent` is unique in the page?

Comment: My guess is, there is an issue with specificity of css due to which its not getting visible

Answer (score 0):

There are things

1. There is unbalanced `button` tag and an `a` tag. Remove the `</a`>
2. Secondly by default you can `hide` or `show` the dropdown. In this case by default it is hiding  & on click it is toggling the class

```js
function mypageMenuDropDown() {
  var dropdownContent = document.getElementById('dropDownContent');
  dropdownContent.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul id="header">
      <li id="logo"><a class="headerDiv" href='.'>FLAGTAG</a></li>
      <div id="menu">
        <li id="login"><a class="headerDiv" href="model/logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li>
        <li id="mypage"><button class="headerDiv" onclick="mypageMenuDropDown()">MYPAGE</button></li>
        <div id="dropDownContent" class="dropDownContent hide">
          <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=join">CALANDER</a>
          <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=routine">ROUTINE</a>
          <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=DIET">DIET</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on assumption that issue is caused due to CSS specificity.

Following is a sample that might cause issue:

```js
function mypageMenuDropDown() {
  var dropdownContent = document.getElementById('dropDownContent');
  dropdownContent.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
#dropDownContent {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul id="header">
      <li id="logo"><a class="headerDiv" href='.'>FLAGTAG</a></li>
      <div id="menu">
        <li id="login"><a class="headerDiv" href="model/logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li>
        <li id="mypage"><button class="headerDiv" onclick="mypageMenuDropDown()">MYPAGE</a></li>
          <div id="dropDownContent" class="dropDownContent">
            <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=join">CALANDER</a>
            <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=routine">ROUTINE</a>
            <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=DIET">DIET</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

You can change the selector to be more specific so that it gets higher precedence over default styles

```js
function mypageMenuDropDown() {
  var dropdownContent = document.getElementById('dropDownContent');
  dropdownContent.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
#dropDownContent {
  display: none;
}

#dropDownContent.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul id="header">
      <li id="logo"><a class="headerDiv" href='.'>FLAGTAG</a></li>
      <div id="menu">
        <li id="login"><a class="headerDiv" href="model/logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li>
        <li id="mypage"><button class="headerDiv" onclick="mypageMenuDropDown()">MYPAGE</a></li>
          <div id="dropDownContent" class="dropDownContent">
            <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=join">CALANDER</a>
            <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=routine">ROUTINE</a>
            <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=DIET">DIET</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mypageMenuDropDown() {
 var dropDownContent = document.getElementById("dropDownContent").classList;
 
 
 if (dropDownContent.contains("show")) {
 
    dropDownContent.remove("show");
 
 } else {
 
    dropDownContent.add("show");
 
 }
 

  }
```

```css
.dropDownContent{ display:none;}
.show{ display:block;}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul id="header">
      <li id="logo"><a class="headerDiv" href='.'>FLAGTAG</a></li>
      <div id="menu">
        <li id="login"><a class="headerDiv" href="model/logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li>
        <li id="mypage"><button class="headerDiv" onclick="mypageMenuDropDown()">MYPAGE</a></li>
          <div id="dropDownContent" class="dropDownContent">
            <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=join">CALANDER</a>
            <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=routine">ROUTINE</a>
            <a class="headerDiv" href="?menu=DIET">DIET</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```